# How to get audio duration in dart (not flutter)?

Tags: dart, audio, duration

I need to get audio duration (from file and url) in the dart package (NOT IN FLUTTER APP).

When I am trying to use packages from the `pub.dev` (like `just_audio` or similar) I receive an error like next:

```
/.flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
```

So do you know the way how to get the duration in pure dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work only with mp3 files, you are lucky and you can use this package: `mp3_info: ^0.2.0`.

Code example:

```dart
  //url
  var url = Uri.parse('https://some_path/file.mp3');
  var response = await http.get(url);

  final mp3 = MP3Processor.fromBytes(response.bodyBytes);

  //file
  // final mp3 = MP3Processor.fromFile(File('path_to_file'));

  print(mp3.bitrate);
  print(mp3.duration);
```

But if you need to work with other formats, you have to parse the file's byte data according to audio formats specs... or you can try to find some c/c++ libraries and use them through `ffi`.